# iOS 8 freezes at updating UserDefaults object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a queue of objects stored to the `NSUserDefaults`. When I need to add objects to it, I call the following method:

```
+ (void)addCodeToQueue:(Code *)code {
  // Note: userDefaults is a static, initialized variable

  NSDictionary *codeModel = [self generateCodeModelWith:code];

  // Read array from UserDefaults, or create one if nil
  NSMutableArray *codeQueue = [userDefaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"CodeQueue"] ? : [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  // Add code model
  [codeQueue addObject:codeModel];

  // Add/replace array & sync
  [userDefaults setObject:codeQueue forKey:@"CodeQueue"]; // App freezes here if uncommented
  [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

My app freezes when I call `setObject:forKey`. If I add a breakpoint to that line, the continue running, it works. If I don't break, it freezes.

This started happening after I updated Xcode to version 8 and started using the new SDK.
Any hints on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this problem in several apps as well -- it appears that by returning the mutable array via mutableArrayValueForKey, you can get stuck in a mutex lock.  For my code, I swapped this out by:

- Getting an immutable array as NSArray *arrSource = [defaults arrayForKey:strKey];
- Copying the data into a mutable array:
  NSMutableArray *arrMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrSouce];
- Setting my values in arrMutable...
- Storing the "modified" array back into the defaults:
  [defaults setObject:arrMutable forKey:strKey];

... for me, at least, this has fixed the mutex lock issue.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Is it better to store it as an immutable array or it won't make any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't matter once you store it -- anything you put into the NSUserDefaults system will be stored immutably, even if it comes from a mutable object.  And glad it worked! I'm in the process of fixing some old apps we had that were hanging for the same reason.

Comment: In my case it worked in reverse, I must save as NSArray. Weird things happen in iOS 8. :-(

Comment: In my case it is freezing on "[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:key]". It is really strange for me

Answer (score 1):

After my experiment, I have found the minimum code required to generate a mutex lock.
The code is as follows.

```
NSMutableArray *videoArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] mutableArrayValueForKey:VIDEOKEY];
[videoArray addObject:item];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:videoArray forKey:VIDEOKEY];
```

There are 3 points to pay attention to:

1. If I delete `[videoArray addObject:item];`, the app will crash.
2. The mutex lock is occurring in `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:videoArray forKey:VIDEOKEY];`.
3. If I make a breakpoint at `[videoArray addObject:item];`, the mutex lock is still exist. If I make it at `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:videoArray forKey:VIDEOKEY];`, the mutex lock will not exist.

**It can be inferred that the mutex lock is result by `[NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray addObject:];` and `[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]`**

By the way, my solution to solve it is as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableVideoArray;
NSArray *videoArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:VIDEOKEY];
if (videoArray)
     mutableVideoArray = [videoArray mutableCopy];
else
    mutableVideoArray = [NSMutableArray array];

if (![mutableVideoArray containsObject:item])
{
    [mutableVideoArray addObject:item];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mutableVideoArray forKey:VIDEOKEY];
}
```